# LEM Sensor's output for current polarity change

Tags: current, sensor, motordriver

I have a project where I'm trying to build a DC Drive, using just analog circuits. I'm expected to show the operation of the drive in forward and reverse motoring, and I'm trying to pick between the following two sensors, and I'm having trouble understanding the differences between them. Ideally I want a current sensor that can give me a positive voltage (4-5V) for +5A and -4 or -5 V for -5A. A dc offset is okay.
Not sure which one to pick.

HX 05-P
https://www.lem.com/en/product-list/hx-05p

https://www.lem.com/sites/default/files/products_datasheets/hx_03_50-p_ver15.pdf

HX 05-P/SP2
https://www.lem.com/en/product-list/hx-05psp2

https://www.lem.com/sites/default/files/products_datasheets/hx%203_50-p_sp2_e%20v07.pdf

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The -P/SP2 part uses a single positive supply; its output is offset 2.5V, and its output "gain" (transresistance, actually) is 0.625 V at nominal current.  The -P part requires a positive and negative supply.  Its output has no offset, gain is 4V at nominal current.

Which one to choose probably depends mainly on whether or not you have a negative supply voltage available